# converting string to jsx component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I achieved converting a piece of string into a component

```
function App() {
  const text = "Please make sure this is BUTTON";
  const modText = text.replace(/ /g, ", ");
  const parts = modText.split(",");
  const mapped = parts.map((part) => {
    return part.match(/BUTTON/) ? <button>{part}</button> : part;
  });
  return <div>{mapped}</div>;
}
```

but the output in the image looks really weird when I combine it back

[image]

I wanted it to become one sentence again something like

[image]

just one sentence not with " " every word

Comment: Why does it matter? The rendered output should be the same

Comment: You'll need to `join()` the array to get a string.

Comment: Use split to split a string to an array.  Use join to merge an array to a string.

Comment: @0stone0 that will output `Please make sure this is[object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
function App() {
  const text = "Please make sure this is BUTTON";
  const parts = text.split(/(BUTTON)/);
  const mapped = parts.map((part,i) => i&1 ? <button key={i}>{part}</button> : part || null);
  return <div>{mapped}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Still not really sure why it's needed

Comment: thanks @Thomas quick question though what's i&1 for?

Comment: @Skkrtskrtbroom it's a condition. Assume `const text = "a BUTTON and a BUTTON and a BUTTON and a BUTTON...";` all occurances of "BUTTON" will be at odd indices in `parts` while the strings will be at even indices! *(For this regular expression. If your regex contains more than one group, the indexing will differ!)*

Comment: @Skkrtskrtbroom counter question, what's the `part || null` part for? why not just `part`? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join() the array to get a string.

Comment: `join()` will stringify the JSX component, which is not wanted. It will output `Please make sure this is[object Object]`

Comment: And if you put in dangerousInnerHtml ?

Comment: This is not asked in the question.